# Python: Empty spaces(those with 0's) in lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to create a function which returns the empty slots in this list:

```
grid = [[0,0,0,4],[0,0,4,2],[2,4,4,2],[0,8,4,2]]
```

The empty slots in this case is those slots with zeroes.

This was my program for it:

```
def empty_slots():
    lst = []
    for i in grid:
        for j in grid:
            if j == 0:
                lst = lst + [(i,j)]
    return lst
```

However, when I run this program I get an empty list `[]`. And the function should output: `[(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (3,0)]`. Note: I'm using Python 2.7.

Comment: Hint: See what `for i in grid: print(i)` prints.

Comment: @PM2Ring It just prints what is in the grid

Comment: Exactly. `for i in grid:` iterates over the items in `grid`, it doesn't iterate over their indices.

Comment: @PM2Ring Oh, I see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in grid:` iterates over the *items in `grid`*, it doesn't iterate over their indices. However, you can get the indices as you iterate over the items of an iterable via the built-in `enumerate` function:

```
def empty_slots(grid):
    return [(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(grid) 
        for j, v in enumerate(row) if not v]

grid = [[0,0,0,4],[0,0,4,2],[2,4,4,2],[0,8,4,2]]

print(empty_slots(grid))
```

**output**

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)]
```

Here's the same thing using "traditional" `for` loops instead of a list comprehension.

```
def empty_slots(grid):
    zeros = []
    for i, row in enumerate(grid):
        for j, v in enumerate(row):
            if v == 0:
                zeros.append((i, j))
    return zeros
```

In this version I use the explicit test of `v == 0` instead of `not v`; the latter will test true if `v` is any "falsey" value, eg, 0, or an empty string, list, tuple, set or dict.

---

You don't *need* `enumerate` to do this. You *could* do this:

```
def empty_slots(grid):
    zeros = []
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        row = grid[i]
        for j in range(len(row)):
            if row[j] == 0:
                zeros.append((i, j))
    return zeros
```

However, it is considered more Pythonic to iterate directly over the items in an iterable, so this sort of thing is generally avoided, when practical:

```
for i in range(len(grid)):
```

Occasionally you *will* need to do that sort of thing, but usually code like that is a symptom that there's a better way to do it. :)

Comment: Oh, I understand now, But is there a way to iterate it without the enumerate function?

Comment: From looking at this, I understand it more clearly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In list comprehension:

```
grid = [[0,0,0,4],[0,0,4,2],[2,4,4,2],[0,8,4,2]]

[(i,j) for i,b in enumerate(grid) for j,a in enumerate(b) if a==0]

Out[81]: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (3, 0)]
```

Comment: Nice and simple one-liner.

Comment: List comprehensions are an unsuitable answer for a new Python user having trouble with iteration.